# How to set timeout in the fetch function in react native

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have a fetch function as following:

```
RequestLogin(params){
 let {username,password}=params;
 try{
   let response = fetch('URL',{
     method:'POST',
     headers:{
      'Accept' : 'application/json',
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
     },   
     body:JSON.stringify({
      username,
      password
     })
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(responseJson=> {
       console.log(responseJson);
     })
    } catch(error){
       console.log(error);
    }
```

I want to know how can I set a timeout to that?

Thanks, advance.

Comment: why do you want a timeout in fetch?

Comment: Because I want to show a message after the timeout. for example, if the app can't connect to the server, I show a message to the user after 2 seconds.

Comment: I have post an answer, you can use that to show message after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a promise that could be `awaited` as

```
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

and when you call your `function` that uses a `fetch function` as you have provided above

```
// Inside some async wrapped func
    await timeout(4000);
    await RequestLogin(params)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I want if the app could not connect to the server, I show a message to the user after several seconds: 'connection failed!'. can I do that with your answer?

Comment: Yes if you want to show a `react-native Alert` after several seconds , just add `await Alert.alert('Error', 'Connection Failed')` in the await chain as per the use case after timeout.